# How put html tags into XSL stylesheet?

Tags: python, xslt

I have python script that converts data.xml to html using stylesheet.xsl.
And i have a problem with inserting html tags into the stylesheet.
I would like to put all the generated values into table cells. maybe someone experienced could help me?

```
  xsl:choose
    xsl:when test="$NECoords = 'true'"
      xsl:value-of select="concat($PtStr, $NthStr, $EastStr, $ElevStr, '  ', $TimeStr, $hzPrec, $vtPrec, $PDOP, $aRMS, $NbrSat, $NbrInt)"/>
    /xsl:when>
```

I would like to know how to put above concatenated strings into table cells in output html file, like:
[image]
 Every value should be put to separate cell, like this:
[image]

Comment: I don't think anyone's going to follow your links. You need to cut the problem down in size. And you need to explain what the problem is: instead of just saying you have a problem, say what output you want, what you tried, and what effect this had.

Comment: Are you asking how to output elements? Read http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#section-Creating-Elements-and-Attributes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

how about using

```
string-join( (concat('<td>',$firsElement),..(elements)..,concat($lastElement,'</td>') ) ,'</td><td>')
```

I think that this code would generate something like

```
<td>$firstElement</td><td>$secEl</td><td>..(n-cells)..</td><td>$lastElement</td>
```

I don't know if there are problems with the `<td>` elements, in this case you have to escape them (`&lt; &gt;`).

maybe you have to add this snippet to the xsl:stylesheet declaration.

```
xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/02/xpath-functions"
```

http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_functions.asp#string

Comment: Thanks, it seems exactly what i'm going to do but i'm getting error with your code:(

Comment: The final error is: 'The value of attribute "select" associated with an element type "xsl:value-of" must not contain the '<' character.' Doesn't matter if I put <> or &lt; &gt;